react vite ffmpeg how to resolve worker module returning 404
I have imported the js, wasm, and worker modules into my project
https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core@0.12.6/dist/esm/ffmpeg-core.js
https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core@0.12.6/dist/esm/ffmpeg-core.wasm
https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core-mt@0.12.2/dist/esm/ffmpeg-core.worker.js
and upon calling the function that the load is in, i get the error in the worker module
Request URL:
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/worker.js?worker_file&type=module
Status Code:
404 Not Found
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
In order to resolve this issue i have added these to my config and looked at similar issues with different threads https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/issues/532
but with no luck. The load also never completes.
CONFIG:
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => ({
//other config stuff
  plugins: [react()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ["@ffmpeg/ffmpeg", "@ffmpeg/util"]
  },
  server: {
    headers: {
      "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin",
      "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp"
    }
  }
}));

FILE:
import { FFmpeg } from "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg";
import { fetchFile, toBlobURL } from "@ffmpeg/util";
 const ffmpeg = new FFmpeg();
    await ffmpeg.load({
      coreURL: await toBlobURL(
        `${importedURL}/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-core.js`,
        "text/javascript"
      ),
      wasmURL: await toBlobURL(
        `${importedURL}/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-core.wasm`,
        "application/wasm"
      ),
      workerURL: await toBlobURL(
        `${importedURL}/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-core.worker.js`,
        "text/javascript"
      )
    });


Following this thread on reddit, i managed to set it up correctly for my application to transcode a video file to .mp3:
https://www.reddit.com/r/react/comments/1cuqe2r/spent_3_hours_implementing_ffmpeg_in_react_here/
My imports look like this:
import { FFmpeg } from "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg";
import { fetchFile } from "@ffmpeg/util";
import coreURL from "@ffmpeg/core?url";
import wasmURL from "@ffmpeg/core/wasm?url";

the relevant executing snippet is:
if (!loaded) await ffmpeg.load({ coreURL, wasmURL });

ffmpeg.on("progress", onFfmpegTranscodingProgress);
var inputVideoFileName = file.name;
var fileNameWithoutExtension = file.name.split(".")[0];
var outputAudioFileName = fileNameWithoutExtension + ".mp3";

await ffmpeg.writeFile(inputVideoFileName, await fetchFile(file));
await ffmpeg.exec(["-i", inputVideoFileName, outputAudioFileName]);
const fileData = await ffmpeg.readFile(outputAudioFileName);

const data = new Uint8Array(fileData as ArrayBuffer);
const audioBlob = new Blob([data.buffer], { type: "audio/mp3" });
const outputFile = new File([audioBlob], outputAudioFileName, 
    { type: "audio/mp3", });
return outputFile;

My vite.config.ts:
export default defineConfig({
    optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["@ffmpeg/ffmpeg", "@ffmpeg/util"] },
    server: {
        headers: {
            "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin",
            "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp",
        }
    }
});

